# mapping Array into Elements with v-for into html attribure

Tags: javascript, vue.js

if posible insert elements to mapping array into html element like this?

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

i use the  directive to render a list of items based on an array.

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <div class ="{{ item.message }}">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and vue throw me this:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li>
    <div class ="{{ item.message }}">
    </div>
    <div class ="{{ item.message }}">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

how can I do that with vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off; Don't use `{{}}` in attributes, use `v-bind` directive or `:` for short:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <div v-bind:class ="item.message">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or simpler:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <div :class ="item.message">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```